# Downloading file using download manager android.How to check whether file gets downloaded completely

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an app which downloads pdf from Google drive and opens it in a Pdf viewer.Once a file gets downloaded it opens the file in pdf viewer(if it is present in android phone). You can open that file again by clicking on the same link.

But sometimes what happens is that file download is interrupted in between due slow net or some other problem. Because of which when user opens that file it shows "corrupted File".

So how to delete that file and check whether that is corrupted or not through the app.

Please Reply..
Thanks in Advance

public class PDFTools {

```
private static String file;

private static final String PDF_MIME_TYPE = "application/pdf";
public static ProgressDialog progress = null;

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(final Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
    return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}


/**
 * If a PDF reader is installed, download the PDF file and open it in a reader.
 * Otherwise ask the user if he/she wants to view it in the Google Drive online PDF reader.<br />
 * <br />
 * <b>BEWARE:</b> This method
 *
 * @param context
 * @param pdfUrl
 * @return
 */


public static void showPDFUrl(final Context context, final String pdfUrl, final String name) {
    if (isPDFSupported(context)) {
        downloadAndOpenPDF(context, pdfUrl, name);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "PDF NOT SUPPORTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (pdfUrl == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "NOT AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Downloads a PDF with the Android DownloadManager and opens it with an installed PDF reader app.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param pdfUrl
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public static void downloadAndOpenPDF(final Context context, final String pdfUrl, final String name) {

    // Get filename
     //final String filename = pdfUrl.substring( pdfUrl.lastIndexOf( "/" ) + 1 );
    // The place where the downloaded PDF file will be put

    final File tempFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), name);

    if (tempFile.exists()) {

        try {
            boolean bool = tempFile.canRead();
            // If we have downloaded the file before, just go ahead and show it.
            if (bool) {
                openPDF(context, Uri.fromFile(tempFile));
                return;
            }else{
                tempFile.delete();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // Show progress dialog while downloading
    if (PDFTools.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, context.getString(R.string.pdf_show_local_progress_title), context.getString(R.string.pdf_show_local_progress_content), true);
        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


        // Create the download request
        DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(pdfUrl));
        r.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, name);
        r.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        r.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        r.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        r.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (!progress.isShowing()) {
                    return;
                }
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);

                progress.dismiss();
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
                Cursor cursor = dm.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));
                Log.d("filepath", Environment.getExternalStorageState());


                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    Log.d("In move to first", "Inside first if");

                    int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                    int reason = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                            if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                                file = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
                                // So something here on success
                            } else {
                                int message = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));
                                File file1 = new File(file);
                                file1.delete();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                cursor.close();
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        dm.enqueue(r);
        // Enqueue the request
```

//           long id= dm.enqueue(r);
//            dm.remove(id);

```
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Check Your Network Connectivity",


                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}


/**
 * Show a dialog asking the user if he wants to open the PDF through Google Drive
 * @param context
 * @param pdfUrl
 */

/**
 * Open a local PDF file with an installed reader
 *
 * @param context
 * @param localUri
 */
public static final void openPDF(Context context, Uri localUri) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(localUri, PDF_MIME_TYPE);
    try {
        context.startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        File file1 = new File(file);
        file1.delete();
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if any apps are installed that supports reading of PDF files.
 *
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isPDFSupported(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    final File tempFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "test.pdf");
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(tempFile), PDF_MIME_TYPE);
    return context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason that `if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL)` does not work?

Comment: It is working when the file gets downloaded completely. When there is some network problem,download stops in between the control doesn't go in the if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL). When network problems occurs while downloading a file, downloading stops in between , then clicking on the same link gives file corrupted error